# Laravel 5.4. Error at call: php artisan db:seed

Tags: laravel

I call the command:
`php artisan db:seed` in Laravel 5.4. The console print me this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a
>   default v     alue (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_     at`) values (user,
>   $2y$10$YAPLstS9Q/Z7vdL82oefieAo4ZToe4xAiNkLF4nygnniKDhWB     njwO,
>   2017-08-02 16:00:42, 2017-08-02 16:00:42))
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a
>   default value

I try set in `database.php` file: 
`'strict' => false`, but this isn`t working. Ho fix this problem?

Comment: Generally email fields are required and should be unique in laravel users table, you are not using email fields in the query.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: you should set the email field

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

In your command line do: `php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder`. You can see the same file being created in `database\seeds` folder now go to the file `UsersTableSeeder.php` you will see `run()` method, write the codes as below:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => str_random(10),
        'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
    ]);
}
```

Now after this you can use: `php artisan db:seed` to seed the database or you can do: `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder` to seed only your `UsersTableSeeder` And final step go to file `DatabaseSeeder.php` in `database/seed` and in `run()` function type this:

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Or you don't need to create `UsersTableSeeder` you can simply copy

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => str_random(10),
    'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
]);
```

into `run()` function in `DatabaseSeeder.php` file

Hope this helps.